# Convert date into numeric date

Tags: string, matlab, date

In Matlab, how can I convert a date into a numeric date?
For example, I want to convert '31-Jan-1990' to '19900131'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) to change the date format to 19900131, and then use [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to convert it to a number:

```
numDate = str2double(datestr('31-Jan-1990','yyyymmdd'))

numDate =
    19900131
```

If you want to keep the date as a string just remove `str2double` from the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two functions that are the most helpful and appropriate ones for this situation: 
[`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html)

The first step is to convert your string to Matlab's date number, which can be later converted to any string format, or even do calculation for date or time. Here we use additional argument to help on conversion. You may also check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html#inputarg_formatIn) for format you like to construct.

```
daynum = datenum('31-Jan-1990','dd-mm-YYYY')
```

The second step is then straightforward. You use the date number to translate to the string with the format you want.

```
datestr(daynum,'YYYYmmdd');
```

You can sure combine both functions together

```
datestr(datenum('31-Jan-1990','dd-mm-YYYY'),'YYYYmmdd')
```

The result

```
>> datestr(datenum('31-Jan-1990','dd-mm-YYYY'),'YYYYmmdd')

ans =

'19900131'
```

Finally, use `str2num` to achieve what you want.